# How to filter array with Nokogiri (search, filter, conditions etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have an XML document which I need to parse with Nokogiri however I need to filter out all 'role' nodes which names do not match those requested.

Essentially I want to return an array of only those *roles* where the first and last name match those required.

*Current Status:*

I have all the code working except for the one filtering/search line from within the controller. I have had a look through the *filter* and *search* functions of Nokogiri but cannot seem to achieve the desired result.

**XML Input**

```
<xml>
<role xsi:type="director"> 
 <firstName>Thomas</firstName> 
 <lastName>JONES</lastName>
 <company>Jones Enterprises</company>
</role>
<role xsi:type="director"> 
 <firstName>Thomas</firstName> 
 <lastName>TEST</lastName>
 <company>Test Factory</company>
</role>
</xml>
```

**Controller**

```
firstname = 'Thomas'
lastname = 'JONES'

@results = doc.css('role').where((doc.css('firstName').text == @firstname) AND (doc.css('lastName').text == @lastname))
```

**View**

```
<%= @results.each do |t| %>
  <%= t.company %>
<% end %>
```

**Required Output**

```
Jones Enterprises
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let the libXML2 underpinnings do the work for you using XPath:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
<role xsi:type="director"> 
 <firstName>Thomas</firstName> 
 <lastName>JONES</lastName>
 <company>Jones Enterprises</company>
</role>
<role xsi:type="director"> 
 <firstName>Thomas</firstName> 
 <lastName>TEST</lastName>
 <company>Test Factory</company>
</role>
</xml>
EOT

FIRSTNAME = 'Thomas'
LASTNAME = 'JONES'

roles = doc.search("//role[child::firstName[text()[contains(., 'Thomas')]] and child::lastName[text()[contains(., 'JONES')]]]")
puts roles.to_xml
# >> <role xsi:type="director"> 
# >>  <firstName>Thomas</firstName> 
# >>  <lastName>JONES</lastName>
# >>  <company>Jones Enterprises</company>
# >> </role>
```

You can do the same with CSS, only CSS doesn't let us use the logic to test two child nodes' content in the same libXML call. Instead, at that point, we have to make multiple calls and let Ruby and Nokogiri filter for the desired nodes which gets to be more difficult and CPU-intensive. Something like this works:

```
roles_firstnames = doc.search('role firstName:contains("Thomas")').map(&:parent)
roles_lastnames = doc.search('role lastName:contains("JONES")').map(&:parent)
matching_roles = (roles_firstnames & roles_lastnames)
puts matching_roles.map(&:to_xml) 
# >> <role xsi:type="director"> 
# >>  <firstName>Thomas</firstName> 
# >>  <lastName>JONES</lastName>
# >>  <company>Jones Enterprises</company>
# >> </role>
```

Notice:

- Nokogiri lets us use a lot of CSS extensions provided by jQuery, such as `:contains`.
- `roles_firstnames & roles_lastnames` is letting Ruby use a set intersection on the array. Each array contains a list of nodes containing the first or last names. Each entry is the parent node's identifier. [`&`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-26) simplifies the test to see what nodes in the two arrays are in common, and basically does an `and` followed by a `uniq` for us.

Either way you do it, once you have the `<role>` nodes needed, it's easy to iterate over them and extract the child `<company>` node's text:

```
roles.map{ |n| n.at('company').text }
# => ["Jones Enterprises"]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you selecting roles like this:

```
@roles = x.css('role').select {|r| firstname == r.at('firstName').text and lastname == r.at('lastName').text }
```

You should use the variables inside select block which contain filter params.

And in your view you reading refined XML nodes like this:

```
<% @roles.each do |r| %>
  <%= r.at('company').text %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It'd be better to process `@roles` in the controller, and create a simple hash or array containing all the sub-information needed, ready to be used in the view.

Comment: Sure.  Even better is to move this routine to some model.

Comment: It's OK to say so in an answer. Stack Overflow isn't just about answering the question asked, it's about answering with better ways of doing something. People ask questions based on the problem they see at hand, but often, because of experience, we see that where they are isn't optimal and they most likely got there by doing something wrong. (The "[XY Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)") and they don't know enough to ask about the first problem that put them where they are. What's annoying is that short-sighted/ignorant people then down vote us. :-/